# stuff function in excel

Tags: sql, excel, function

Is there an equivalent of SQL function `STUFF` in Excel or Excel VBA? I want exact function shown here with all the parameters, especially parameter `length`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql

Comment: It depends on what you're looking for - are you looking for a function that can replace a section of a string with some replacement string? Or are you mistaking the fact that `FOR XML` is commonly  abused to perform string concatenation and that `STUFF` is then used to  minimally alter the final result but since `STUFF` appears first in such usage, you're assuming it does the bulk of the work and thus looking for a string concatenation function?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Syntax** of `STUFF` is `STUFF( source_string, start, length, add_string )`

---

#### Solution 1

Using formula

```
=LEFT(A1,C1-1) & B1 & MID(A1,C1+D1,LEN(A1)-C1-D1+1)
```

where,
`Cell A1` - *source_string*
`Cell B1` - *add_string*
`Cell C1` - *start*
`Cell D1` - *length*

---

#### Solution 2

Using `UDF` in excel VBA

```
Public Function Stuff(textStr As String, start As Long, count As Long, replaceStr As String) As String
    Stuff = Left(textStr, start - 1) & replaceStr & Mid(textStr, start + count)
End Function
```

where,
`textStr` - *source_string*
`start` - *start*
`count` - *length*
`replaceStr` - *add_string*

Here, `start > 0`  and  `count >= 0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try 'replace' function in Excel

Excel:
=REPLACE("To be or not to be", 1, 18," that’s the question")

Comment: This will give results different from expected in case of more occurrences of search string in source string.